# NestJS self signed certificate for SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, nestjs, backend

I want to use my NestJS backend with https. Now if I run it and connect to it, I get a `Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` error because well, it's self signed. So my question is: How can I get a valid certificate for `<my-ip>:3000`?

Comment: In short: you will not be able to get a publicly trusted IP certificate for a private (reserved) IP address since you are not the sole owner of this IP (could be used in any other local nets). For public IP address there are CA which provide you with the necessary certificates. Ports don't matter.